# Link only answers on review: they should be processed different way - transfer ownership to user who had improved it

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, link-only-answers

There should be official possibility to "take ownership on it" after answer was improved.

Just delete the answer - is not a good choice since better is to have link then nothing. Now available ways to deal with them:

1) delete and then create new with more information but (put the link) - is something that can provoke unpleasant discussions.

2) delete and create new without the link - unfair

3) "Just edit it" - it is nice but it could not be done as part of Review (and is not part of the Game).

In any case when there is only one link-only answer under the question - to delete it works against SO. There is no mechanics under the review to prevent it or to encourage reviewers to save it one way or another.

Comment: There is nothing to save here. That is what Google is for. Information (solution) already exists on the Internet.

Comment: If google would help in all cases SO would not exist

Comment: Create new answer is what I propose. Just declaring "that previous link-only answer" was used. And improve review instruments for it.

Comment: If users that post such answers want to stick around, we need to teach them the correct way to do that.  They need to know that link only answers are not good, and they need to know what to do about them.

Comment: Imho, it's not done by simply copying the content of the website to the answer. This would violate copyright of the original website. So the content would have to be paraphrased which I'd consider a large amount of work just to fix someone else answer.

Comment: "They need to know that link only answers are not good" - when somebody take ownership of your answer - it is enough strength signal to understand it. Bet when somebody delete your correct answer - "because it is a link" - when there are no other answers  - you will just understand what kind of dumb mincing machine  you met.

Comment: @BDL , I do not propose to copy the content, I propose to add the summary, but I agree that this can provoke copy the content. Thank you for this real consideration.

Comment: Someone editing your question isn't, "taking ownership".  They get no rewards (except maybe 2 rep) for doing so; the original poster gets it all.  The answer being correct is irrelevant; if it's only a link, it doesn't withstand the test of time, therefore should be deleted.  If the poster doesn't want it deleted, they can edit in the relevant information, as the recommend deletion reason states.

Comment: To take/transfer an ownership on improved "link only" - that is what I propose.

Comment: You've just *stated* that you think it's bad to post your own new answer, when you want to post your own, entirely original, answer to a given question, and that you'd rather edit your own, entirely original, answer into someone else's answer, and then have that answer transfer ownership to you instead.  That makes no sense.  Post your own new answer when you have your own new answer to post.

Comment: @servy SO do not provide motivation to do it (add new answer). but SO motivates reviewers just to delete link-only. 5 clicks , it is gone and nothing can be improved. That is how I see it.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij The answer would get upvotes if it was actually a good answer that others found useful.  There's not much in the way of motivation to *delete* the answer, other than an intrinsic motivation to make the site better by removing bad answers.

Comment: you always repeat "bad answer", "bad answer" like it would be your mantra. you do not delete "bad answer", you delete link only answer believing that it is "bad".

Comment: ...because a link only answer **is** bad.  It does the same thing old forums did, and still do; give you a link and go, "Here, try this."  So in a few years, when you yourself have the problem, you find this post.  You click the link, and it's dead.  And now you're frustrated, because someone had the same problem, and rather than just write out the solution, they linked elsewhere, and now you have no idea where to go or what to do.

Comment: This is not my religion.

Comment: What is the end goal, here?  For us to allow link-only answers?  To delete them quicker?  To change the entire answering process to allow someone to co-opt someone else's answer and make it yours?  I'm having trouble seeing what it is you want to happen, here.

Comment: Two goals: 1) to declare that this link-only answer was edited/appended to full answer by me, and now I own it and receive all bonuses (it is more correct and fair then current available possibilities) 2) encourage reviewers to do not delete "link only answers but improve them" (if they are on topic of course).

Comment: 1) Will not happen.  The post owner owns the post, and I daresay there's some legalities in transferring that ownership to someone else.  2) Will also not happen.  Link only answers get deleted if not edited.  If you want to edit, feel free, but it is not required.  Trying to make it required won't do anything but frustrate you due to the negative backlash it receives.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Both of those already exist.  If you want to post your own original answer you only need to post your own answer, rather than editing your own original answer into someone else's, and users are encouraged to do so through upvotes if they do it well.  [meta-tag:status-complete].

Comment: @Servy , everything exist.  edit exists. google exist. internet exist. matrix exist. I am asking about improving review process. the problem is that to delete link only (during review) is much simpler then improve.

Comment: @ fbueckert change "own" to other term. important are bonuses. bonuses are mine.  but I would like to declare that I have used the link-only posted by other user - it is fair play.

Comment: Then post your own answer.  I'm not seeing why that's such a hard thing to do.

Comment: In current circumstances it would provoke not pleasant discussions (rules, moral etc.) . I'm asking function to declare it "officially" using SO provided UI. This should confirm that SO allows such behavior. And again "edit by your own" or "do it with google" are not correct answers in discussion about review process.

Comment: I don't see why you'd even have to argue that; the link-only answer will be deleted, and your post, which summarizes the link, won't be.  As long as you're doing more than a straight copy paste from the linked page, there's nothing really actionable there.  As for reviewing, the process is simple: Is it a link-only answer?  Downvote and/or recommend deletion.  That's it.  Run into it organically? Downvote and/or flag.  An optional step for *either* process is to post your own answer.

Comment: We use two different SO. Or you do not know what is a review  mincing machine. Link only will be flagged and deleted in a moment. Less chances to meet somebody who can improve them. Do not hear my, opponents say "it is normal to delete only one link only".

Comment: If you're not going to review correctly, you shouldn't be reviewing.  In fact, you'll quickly encounter audits that will *tell* you that, and eventually prevent you from doing so.  In a review, link only answers should be deleted.  If you're not a fan of that, best you can do is skip.

Comment: It is what you choose best for you. Best for me is to state that this should be improved.

Comment: Most readers disagree this is actually an improvement.  I'm one of those that disagree.

Comment: What if most of those users have deleted the only linkonly answers many time - could they change theirs understanding of what is good now?. Not you of course, I see it.

Comment: Please read this: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370): "So let me be clear: this sort of response [link-only answer] is not an answer. If you see this, flag it. Moderators, if you see it flagged, **delete it**."

Comment: You mentioned "*In current circumstances it would provoke not pleasant discussions (rules, moral etc.)*". No, there's nothing wrong with using their links and post a better answer (also give proper credit if you feel generous), but when they post a link-only answer, then it's their own fault that they don't follow the site's policy.

Answer (score 7):

That the only "answer" is a link only answer is not a reason not to delete.

A link only answer is by the site's definition *not an answer*. Leaving it there there is less incentive to post a proper, useful answer.

If someone wants to use the information on the other side of a link in a link-only answer to post a proper answer, they are already welcome to do so.

It's not clear what your proposal would change nor how it would work. But as long as it it implies that useless posts shouldn't be deleted, I do not think is a great idea.

Comment: I propose improve reviewer instruments of "Low quality" queue to encourage reviewers to append such answers. 

2 words about "this is a site defintion !!" as an argument - definitions are only agreements not God Low and as agreements they can be changed. I do not see a reason fall on knees.

Comment: *"If someone wants to use the information on the other side of a link in a link-only answer to post a proper answer, they are already welcome to do so."* But if it gets deleted the user doing that would need 10K rep to see the link. I think this discussion is about ways to keep helpful links even when in a link-only answer.

Comment: Yes that is true, but I propose to include those options to the review. To manage problem in place.

Answer (score 0):

> "Just edit it" - is nice but is neither part of Review or the Game.

Editing is a part of review. The Low Quality Posts queue has an Edit button in the row of review options. First Posts and Late Answers retain the edit link that's normally below posts.

I'm not sure what you mean by "the game" but almost all review queues give you the option to edit a salvageable post right there.

Comment: Current "In place Edit" is limited. Actually you should open question in new tab and check other answers first if you want to edit it. I do the check just to check: is it not only  answer - but this is my own obligation - I understand it.

You can't be serious saying "I'm not sure..."- SO is weeping rock of gamification.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij How is the option to edit within review queues limited? And how is it not part of the gamification of the site? Users can get both reputation and badges for edits. And even if it isn't, why would that matter?